# What is this second parameter in the foreign method in migration Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, foreign-keys, migration

I'm working with Laravel in this new project but there's one piece of code that I don't know what it does.

```
$table->foreign('course_id', '54419_596eedbb6686e')->references('id')->on('courses');
```

The line above is one of my migration files, I know that I'm saying that the 'course_id' is a foreign key with relation to 'id' on courses table. But what I don't know is what is this second parameter ('54419_596eedbb6686e'), if I look in the method description it says that is a name, but a name for what? Am I supposed to create a number like this and put it in all my foreign keys? Is there a command to generate this number?

Anyway if anyone can help me to understand this piece of code it would be great.
Hope I was clear on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter is the name for your foreign key.

By default the name of the foreign key for this `$table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');` will be `courses_course_id_foreign`.

In this case `$table->foreign('course_id', '54419_596eedbb6686e')->references('id')->on('courses');` your foreign key will be named as `54419_596eedbb6686e`.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Thank you very much for this. Let me ask you a couple more things please. This is by any change a good practice? I mean name the foreign key with a value? and if it is, this number is generate by some command?

Comment: @CristhoferAlencar is there any particular reason to name the foreign key with values? i'm not so sure if it's a really good practice, as you won't be able to know what keys it is by just looking at the name and it might get a little confusing for others.

Comment: yeah that's the thing, I actually don't know. I'm working in this project that was already going on and encountered this while working and didn't quite understood the need for this. I agree with you, it is not necessary and it really gets confusing. Anyhow, thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a foreign key you are creating a constraint and that's what the second parameter of `foreign()` function is specifying: the constraint name.

If you are using mysql you can log in the shell(or whatever program you use to check the db out) and run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. that will output information about that table you specified. There you'll be able to see '54419_596eedbb6686e' as a constraint of your table. Something like this:

`CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY (column_id) REFERENCES table_name (id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

You can find a little more information in the following links: [MySQL FOREIGN KEY syntax](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/)
 [SQL FOREIGN KEY on CREATE TABLE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Answer (score 0):

When you create migration let this in your migration for foreign key

```
 $table->foreign('foreign_id')
            ->references('id')->on('main_table_name')
            ->onUpdate('CASCADE')
            ->onDelete('RESTRICT');
```

Comment: @cristhofer-alencar